# Strange "Reference to generic type X should be parameterized"

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Sorry if the title is not very good but I really have no better proposals so they are welcome. And now to the problem:

```
   ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
        new ResponseEntity<String>(SOME_BIG_XML_RESPONSE_STRING, HttpStatus.OK);
    when(restTemplate.exchange(any(URI.class), any(),
          any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

I am using mockito for some tests but I am getting the code in yellow (warning). Do you have any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: `Class` is generic type, hense the warning. Also, rest template most likely returns exactly the generic type of that `Class` you've passed into it.

Comment: Here a hint: you should never use just `any()` because it´s unreadable - there cann be multiple methods with same name... Add more info to get better details.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t use `any(Class.class)` because it´s generic. If you want to say that everything should be OK on this position you can use just `any()`

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(any(URI.class), any(),
          any(HttpEntity.class), any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

I will update more specifiy if you would show codesnippet of the call you want to specify.

Comment: the answer is wrong. If you change "any(Class.class)" to "any()" there is an error stating:
The method exchange(URI, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<Object>) is ambiguous for the type RestTemplate

Comment: also what did you miss? the return type is obviously ResponseEntity